# Time-constraint query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

id | roomid | courseid | day(NUM) | start(TIME) | end(TIME)

This is one part of larget query that I am stuck with. How can I show all id's that have NO time break in between courses in specific rooms on specific day? Kind of stuck here. 
I guess I have to use 'ADDTIME()' function to to find out the difference in course1 end time and course 2start time => that have 0. I have been looking at it for quite some time now and I am stuck!

Comment: Are you asking how one can retrieve, using SQL, all `roomid` for which there are entries in your table that in aggregate span from 00:00 until 23:59 on some given `day`?  If so, I think you'll find this is not something MySQL will easily be able to tell you; you'll probably want to retrieve all room bookings for that day and then scan over them in some other language to determine which (if any) span the whole day.

Comment: You're pretty much correct with your assumption. You could create a view that orders them by `start(TIME)`, then in that view select the `ID`s where `start` of `ID`#x is some value greater than `end` of `ID`#(x-1). I say "some value" because you could specify what constitutes a "time break". (perhaps 5 minutes isn't enough because it's not worth being able to schedule something in that time frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are interested in is full utilisation.
If a day is say 7 hours, (9-5 - 1 hour lunch break), call it 420 minutes to make things easy.
Then 420 - Sum(MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(t2,t1)) = 0 would mean the room was fully booked up.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps toying with a CTE can help you there. Try starting with something like this

```
WITH RU_CTE AS (
    SELECT your_fields
      FROM RoomUtilization
     WHERE day = @DayParameter
       AND start = @startTimeParameter
     UNION ALL
    SELECT your_fields
      FROM RoomUtilization RU
     WHERE day = RU_CTE.day
       AND start = RU_CTE.end
)
SELECT *
  FROM RU_CTE
```

and see if some twiches satisfy your needs

But as eggyal said, it's probably easier to get the data for the day and room and solve this on the application code.